# Operações de soma com sprintf

Tags: php

É possível fazer operações de soma com `sprintf`? No exemplo abaixo, como fazer para diminuir, ou somar *1* na `$idade`?

```
$idade = 10;
$str = '%d anos';
echo sprintf( $str , $idade );
```

Comment: `printf( $str , ++$idade );` serve ou precisa de algo mais especifico? pelo menos foi a unica maneira que conseguiu até agora ... tentei fazer a conta na expressão mas não funcinou.

Comment: @rray, é um pacote de tradução, queria fazer a operação na função, mas acho que não tem como. A sua forma é como estou usando no momento.

Answer (score 0):

Já que `sprintf` é uma função de formatação, não seria incorreto fazer:

```
<?php

$a = 1;
$b = 4;
$str = '%d anos menos %d = %d';

echo sprintf($str, $b, $a, $b-$a);
?>
```

**[Edit]**

```
function somar($a, $b){
    return sprintf('%d anos menos %d = %d', $b, $a, $b-$a);
}

echo somar(1,10);
```

Comment: Isso está correto, mas pretendia fazer com que a própria função fizesse a operação.

Comment: Creio que também é possível, mas tipo, não  sei mais ou menos como quererias :/ que  fossem recebidos, e retornados e dados através de uma função.

Comment: Algo como `sprintf( '%d-1 anos' , 10 )`, para ter um output de `9 anos`.

Comment: Deve ser do jeito como acabaste de escrever ?

Comment: Sim, deveria ser a string `'%d-1 anos'`

Comment: Tipo, tudo que estiver entre aspas, faz apenas parte do modelo a ser formatado, não dá para assinar valores à partir de dentro (dentro das aspas);